# How can I set up a delay before the rotation happens?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I set up a delay before the rotation happens? I tried StartCoroutine, =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a timer?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 500; // Milliseconds
timer.AutoReset = false // Stop it from repeating over and over
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Your Code:

```
if (isRolling) 
{
    transform.position += new Vector3 (0,1,2)
    timer.Start(); // Will wait the "Interval" milliseconds and fire off Elapsed (above)
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend, isn't it possible to do the same thing in a simpler way, using WaitForSeconds? Can you please write a code with WaitForSeconds so I can see what I did wrong? Thank you very much! http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.htm

Comment: Hi! The function unity provides seems to be relatively simple, you would use yield WaitForSeconds(0.5); (assuming it allows less than one second value). Are you getting an error with this function? Can you show us any code related to this that you are having issues with?

Comment: As a side note the documentation mentions: "Suspends the coroutine execution for the given amount of seconds.". If you are executing this in something that is not a "coroutine" (i'm not familiar with what a coroutine is in Unity) - It will  not work and the timer method may be your best bet, or investigating coroutines.

Comment: if (isRolling) 
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3 (0,1,2)
        yield WaitForSeconds(0.5);
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
    }

Comment: I get an error when I type this.

Comment: I think it's incomplete my friend.

Comment: Do you want me to make another question?

Comment: I will accept this one.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you type that?

Comment: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `)', `,', `;', `[', or `='

Comment: You need a semicolon (;) after new Vector3 (0,1,2)

Comment: I have a semicolon. "yield" is in red

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/251961/view.html You need to investigate what coroutines are in the Unity world, yield WaitForSeconds won't work for you in the current context. Alternative measure would be the timer above, but I wouldn't say it scales well.

Comment: ok i will check it out

Comment: I do not get errors anymore, but it still has no effect.

Comment: if (isRolling) 
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3 (0,1,2)
        StartCoroutine(Delay(2.0F));
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
    }

Comment: IEnumerator Delay(float waitTime) 
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
 }

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I will create another question.